# C# Grouping/Sorting a Generic List<> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Im looking to group and sort a Generic List<>. I have a list of objects representing files and each of these objects has a FileName, FileType and FileDate property. FileType is defined as an enumeration.

I have some working code which allows me to group together lists of files by FileType.

```
var fileGroups = fileList.GroupBy(f=> f.FileType)

foreach (var group in fileGroups )
{
   foreach (var file in group)
   {
   }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is order fileGroups by the FileType enumeration value and then each group within fileGroups  by the FileDate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var sortedThing = fileGroups
                  .OrderBy(g => g.Key)             // (1) Order the groups
                  .Select(g => g.OrderBy(f => f.FileDate));   // (2) Order *each* group
```

You need the groups sorted (1) and each of the groups sorted internally (2);

Comment: It doesnt like g.Key in .OrderBy(g => g.Key), its complaining that my object doesn't contain a definition for Key?